# Mein Name ist Hase

Tags: phrase, etymology

This is a phrase often used to indicate *"I don't know anything about that"* or *"I don't understand what happened"*.

I've deduced this meaning from the contexts of the many situations where I encountered it. It seems to be fairly well known throughout Germany and Austria, even occurring in children's stories.

But how did that phrase come about? **What in the world does it actually refer to?!** Is there some original source from which it is (mis)quoted?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answers, would you mind to accept one? (click the check button next to the answer)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I thought I already had done so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There actually *was* a [Mr. Hase](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_von_Hase), of course :)

Comment: Fabelhaft, herzlichen Dank! Das hatte ich nicht erwartet.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It is a link-only answer

Comment: @Alina: I suppose OP must have found the answer useful, somehow.

Answer (score 15):

Endlich kann ich mal als Antwort auf eine Frage einen Link zu einer Seite meiner Datenbank des nutzlosen Wissens posten:
(Edit: Link entfernt)<sup>*</sup>

Für alle, die meine Website nicht besuchen wollen:

Victor von Hase stand 1854/55 in Heidelberg vor Gericht, weil sein verlorener Studentenausweis einem Mörder zur Flucht verholfen hatte. Seine Aussage: »Mein Name ist Hase, ich weiß von nichts!«

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Edit: Ich habe die Datenbank des nutzlosen Wissens im Jahr 2018 eingestellt. Der Link, den ich hier im Jahr 2014 gepostet hatte, funktioniert seitdem nicht mehr, daher habe ich ihn nun entfernt.</sub>

Comment: Sounds like Sargent Schultz: "I know nusssSINK!". Nice website BTW.

Comment: hahaha eine datenbank des unnützen wissens

Comment: @WayneEra: Fast. Nicht »unnütz« sondern »nutzlos«!

Comment: so oder so, nicht dass du mich falsch verstehst, ich liebe nutzloses wissen, wäre einfach noch nie auf die idee gekommen eine datenbank damit zu füllen...^^